# Can I get help to calculate average and total?

Tags: java, arrays, file, class, methods

I have opened a file and it print out fine and it looks a bit like this;

John Hop 13 12.00

Laura Shack 6 15.00

But with an array of 6. Since I have another class with getters and setters, the file is able to get the total pay of each individual:

John 13 12.00 150.00

Laura Shack 6 15.00 120.00

I want to print the total pay of all individual and then get the average.
Here is some of my code

```
public class PayRoll {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 15;

    final String INPUT_FILE = "data.txt";
    Worker[] worker_ar = new Worker[NUMBER_OF_WORKERS];

    Scanner file = null;

    try {

        file = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_FILE));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File Not Found!");
    }

    String line = null;
    int count = 0;
    double total_pay = 0;
    double avg_pay = 0;

    while ((file.hasNextLine()) && (count < worker_ar.length)) {
        String fName = file.next();
        String lName = file.next();
        int hours = file.nextInt();
        double hrly_pay = file.nextDouble();

        worker_ar[count] = new Worker(fName, lName, hours, hrly_pay);

        count++;
//Here, i tried computing the average but it is wrong. 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            total_pay = total_pay + worker_ar[i].computePay();

            avg_pay = total_pay / count;
```

Comment: You don't need to have that `for()` loop inside the while loop. Put it after the `while` loop has run its course, the you sum all the pay into `total_pay` and divide it by `count`. Edit: Just like Elliot's submitted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finish reading in the file contents before calculating the total and average (or at least the average). Something like

```
double total_pay = 0;
while ((file.hasNextLine()) && (count < worker_ar.length)) {
    String fName = file.next();
    String lName = file.next();
    int hours = file.nextInt();
    double hrly_pay = file.nextDouble();
    worker_ar[count] = new Worker(fName, lName, hours, hrly_pay);
    total_pay += worker_ar[count].computePay(); // <-- add this worker's
                                                //     pay to the total.
    count++;
}
double avg_pay = total_pay / count; // <-- calculate the average when 
                                    //     there is a total.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. These small details can really affect a program. thanks again.